# WPF application in MVVM

Tags: wpf, gridview, mvvm, grid

I've developed a WPF application by following the MVVM pattern. What I'm doing is that I have made a `grid` in my views. In the 1st `grid` I'm listing the values in the rows & columns like the following, I also have `textboxes`;

`<GridViewColumn Header="fname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fname}`

After selecting a particular row, all the column values come into the respective `textbox`. In another `grid`, and I can update those values. I also have an UPDATE `button` over there.

What I want is after clicking the Update `button`, the updated row in the 1st `grid` should be shown in a different color. So what code should I write in the cs for implementing that.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you change a property of a row/object set a 'Status' property of the object. You might set it to Changed or Modified. (Make sure the Status Property is a DependencyProperty)
2. In the view that displays the list, bind the color you want to change to the Status property using a ValueConverter.
3. In the ValueConverter return the appropriate color to match the Status.